# Calling a Class Object From a Dictionary as an Object

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of class objects. I need to pull the object to have it perform one of it's functions. The objects do not have variable names, they are made by a `for` loop.

Here's what I tried:

```
    class Pawn(object):
     def legal_moves(self):
         ...
         return moves_list

    ...
    # main
    dictionary = {'a2': <class '__main__.Pawn'>, 'b2': <class '__main__.Pawn'> etc.}

    pawn_obj = dictionary['a2']

    moves = pawn_obj.legal_moves()
```

FULLER VERSION OF CODE:

```
  class Pawn(Piece):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.type = "P"
        super(Pawn, self).__init__(color, self.type)

    def legal_moves(self, position, map):
        self.l_moves = []
        file = int(position[:1])
        rank = int(position[1:])

        if self.color == "w" and rank == 2:
            move1 = str(rank + 1) + str(file)
            move2 = str(rank + 2) + str(file)
            self.l_moves.append(move1)
            self.l_moves.append(move2)
        return self.l_moves

#main
b = Board(white_view=True)

p = Pawn("w")

p = b.map.get("12")
print(type(p))

moves = p.legal_moves("12", b.map)
print(moves)
```

RETURNS:

> ````
> <class '__main__.Pawn'>
>
>  File "C:/Users/" line 173, in <module>
>   moves = p.legal_moves("12", b.map)
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1```
> ````

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve]. where is that error being thrown from? the stack trace should provide the exact line. The only call you make is to `pawn_obj.do_a_thing`, so you should check the type of that

Comment: Please also add the full error message.

Comment: The problem isn't with `pawn_obj`, it's with `pawn_obj.do_a_thing`. Somewhere in your code you're doing something like `self.do_a_thing = <some list>`

Comment: What does `print(pawn_obj.do_a_thing)` show?

Comment: Barmar, you are right. the error is thrown on the line pawn_obj.do_a_thing. do_a_thing returns a list of legal moves for that specific pawn to make

Comment: Not yet a problem, but once the current error is fixed it will be: you've made `do_a_thing()` an instance method.  Your dictionary contains class objects, not instances `Pawn`.  This means `pawn_obj.do_a_thing()` will fail with `TypeError: do_a_thing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.  You can fix this by using the `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorators on `do_a_thing()` and defining it with the parameter `cls` or no parameters, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387595/calling-a-class-object-from-a-dictionary-as-an-object#comment99374951_56387595).

I would CTRL-F the project for `self.legal_moves` looking for a place where its value is set to a list.

The additional code you posted shows that `Pawn` has an attribute `l_moves` that is a list.  Maybe that attribute started life as `Pawn.legal_moves` before you created the `Pawn.legal_moves()` function and you missed renaming it somewhere?

Try adding these debugging lines to get a hint about what that attribute really contains in your case:

```py
p = b.map.get("12")
print(type(p))

# new lines
print(type(p.legal_moves))  # if <class 'list'>, we're on the right track; if <class 'method'> we need to look elsewhere
print(p.legal_moves))  # if it's a list, its contents might give you a clue about where it's being set

moves = p.legal_moves("12", b.map)
```

Comment: You were right, in the super class I had accidentally defined "legal_moves" as a list. Changed that and now it works. Thank you!